# My texturing looks dull, any tips to make it shinier?

Tags: texturing, uv

I'm learning the basics of texturing, and I was trying to add textures to a character I made following [this video](https://youtu.be/JYBPXTful2g?list=PLFt_AvWsXl0fEx02iXR8uhDsVGhmM9Pse). To make it short, I baked the shadows to have the Ambient occlusion, exported them in an image, opened it with GIMP, overlapped the UV grid I exported in another image to it, and colored only that layer. Then I exported it all in the "final texture image", and opened it in Blender.

There's two major things that bug me: the first one is that no matter the color I use to paint the upper level , it always seems too "weak" if compared to the other layer, and the overall effect looks way too dull, as you can see in pic. I used the color you can see in the "grid" that's on the character, but it seems as if the Ambient Occlusion's effect is too strong, making every color I put on it look a lot weaker.

The other thing I can't figure out how to solve is the fact that by doing so I find myself with the grid still visible in the texture: how can I solve this?

And one additional question: is it ok to do as I am doing right now? Baking the shadows, painting on them and having a single image for the texture? And also, is it a problem if I'm working with separate meshes in order to make texturing them simpler? Or should I have all in a single object to do things properly? (I'll also have to animate it)

Give me every advice you can on how to make better textures, and thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: what render engine are you using?

Comment: Blender render, but I can see that it's not the color I want already by the .png texture file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the texture to have colors that 'pop' like the colors that the grid uses, you can enable the 'shadeless' setting under the shading section of the material tab.

The grid is visible because you either exported your texture with it(make sure the grid is not visible when exporting!), you are still in edit mode(which always shows the grid), or you've enabled 'display wireframe' from the display options of the object tab.

Having separate meshes for the same character is OK if it means they are still part of the same object., especially if it means you have to do less work. It is worth noting that you can have multiple UVs for a single mesh, and you can even assign individual materials to individual faces of a mesh, each of them with a unique UV map(generally this is not necessary, but it is possible.)

Comment: in gimp create seperate layers for the uvs and image and then drag the image to the top of the layer stack